# Blazor RemoteAuthenticatorView => OnLogInSucceeded runs multiple times

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I am using `<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="OnLogInSucceeded" />` in the authentication page of a Blazor app and have noticed that it calls "OnLogInSucceeded" multiple times when a user logs in.  I would expect it to only run once.  I have to grab some data from a db when a user logs in and figured this would be the place to do it.  It's not that is gives an error, just retrieving the data 3-4 on each login is inefficient.

Is there a better way/place to make api calls on login?

I'm using Azure B2C..

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this as I am trying to solve the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no, though I'm just starting to use Net 6 and so far does seem to work as expected.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but the AuthenticationState answer on this question sounds like it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617031/using-remoteauthenticatorview-onloginsucceeded-gives-a-second-azuread-login-dial